# Is it necessary that an explicit feature map exists with all kernels?

Tags: kernel-trick

Consider the Radial Basis Kernel
$$K(x,z) = \exp\left(-\frac{\|x−z\|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$

Is it possible to find a feature map in this case?
Is it necessary that an explicit feature map exists with all kernels?

Comment: For your first q: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406726/rbf-kernel-mapping/406737#406737 and second q: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436971/is-it-always-possible-to-find-the-feature-map-from-a-given-kernel